# UITabBar subviews change order

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uitabbar

I'm iterating over UITabBar views like so:

```
for (UIView *view in [tabBar subviews]) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIControl class]]) {
        tabBarItemFrame = [tabBar convertRect:view.frame toView:self.view];
    }
}
```

The order is initially:

```
<_UITabBarBackgroundView: 0x7a62e150; frame = (0 0; 768 49); autoresize = W; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7a62fcd0>>,
<GSBadgeView: 0x7b1b6060; frame = (0 0; 0 0); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x7b1b61d0>>,
<UITabBarButton: 0x7d75ee80; frame = (71 1; 76 48); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7b0eaf80>>,
<UITabBarButton: 0x7d75ef90; frame = (181 1; 76 48); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7b0e7f40>>,
<UITabBarButton: 0x7d75f180; frame = (291 1; 76 48); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7b0c16e0>>,
<UITabBarButton: 0x7d75f6f0; frame = (401 1; 76 48); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7b0278a0>>,
<UITabBarButton: 0x7b026060; frame = (511 1; 76 48); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7b0244d0>>,
<UITabBarButton: 0x7b002960; frame = (621 1; 76 48); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7d7697c0>>,
<UIImageView: 0x7a62fdf0; frame = (0 -1; 768 1); autoresize = W; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7a62bd50>>
```

After exiting the app and returning, however, the order changes to:

```
<_UITabBarBackgroundView: 0x7a62e150; frame = (0 0; 768 49); autoresize = W; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7a62fcd0>>,
<GSBadgeView: 0x7b1b6060; frame = (0 0; 0 0); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x7b1b61d0>>,
<UITabBarButton: 0x7d75ef90; frame = (181 1; 76 48); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7b0e7f40>>,
<UITabBarButton: 0x7d75f180; frame = (291 1; 76 48); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7b0c16e0>>,
<UITabBarButton: 0x7d75f6f0; frame = (401 1; 76 48); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7b0278a0>>,
<UITabBarButton: 0x7b026060; frame = (511 1; 76 48); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7b0244d0>>,
<UITabBarButton: 0x7b002960; frame = (621 1; 76 48); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7d7697c0>>,
<UIImageView: 0x7a62fdf0; frame = (0 -1; 768 1); autoresize = W; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7a62bd50>>,
<UITabBarButton: 0x7d75ee70; frame = (71 1; 76 48); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7b00ea80>>
```

Pretty much, the first tab bar button is at the end of the `subviews` array. Visually the layout is correct and I'm not doing anything to manipulate the subviews.

Can anyone provide any insight here? Should I not rely on subviews to maintain a particular order?

**Update**

As @rmaddy mentions below, digging into subviews was unnecessary. I got the appropriate frame with the bit of code below:

```
NSInteger helpBarButtonIndex = [self.viewControllers indexOfObject:self.helpMenuVC];
UIView *helpBarButton = [[[self.tabBar items] objectAtIndex:helpBarButtonIndex] view];
tabBarItemFrame = [self.tabBar convertRect:helpBarButton.frame toView:self.view];
```

Comment: Your last statement covers it. Why do you need to dig into the subviews of the tab bar?

Comment: @rmaddy  Thanks, digging in to subviews wasn't necessary. I changed up the way I'm getting the frame.